# Scss вложенное правило для отдельного селектора

Tags: css, frontend, sass, scss, препроцессор

Существует ли возможность в scss(sass) создать вложенное правило для отдельного селектора. В scss есть возможность писать стили для детей и имен с родительским префиксом `&`, а мне нужно во вложение добавить внешний селектор. Например код:

```
.one{
  .two,
  &_1,
  &_other{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Скомпилируется в:

```
.one .two,
.one_1,
.one_other{
    color: red;
}
```

А есть ли возможность во внутрь `.one{}` поместить какой-то внешний селектор, чтобы итог был без родителя? Например, я хочу написать что-то вроде:

```
.one{
  .two,
  &_1,
  &_other,
  '/какой-то префикс, поднимающий на уровень вверх/'.class{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

И получить такой код:

```
.one .two,
.one_1,
.one_other,
.class{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: возможно поможет [@at-root](http://sassbreak.com/getting-back-to-our-roots/)

Comment: @Grundy поможет! Как раз то что нужно, можете оформить ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это возможно стало сделать с 3.4 версии `Sass`.

Используй `@at-root`.

### Пример №1

Sass:

```
.one{
   @at-root .two#{&},
  &_1,
  &_other{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Css:

```
.two.one, .one_1, .one_other {
  color: red;
}
```

### Пример №2:

Sass:

```
.one{
   @at-root #{&}.two,
  &_1,
  &_other{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Css:

```
.one.two, .one_1, .one_other {
  color: red;
}
```

### Пример №3

Scss:

```
.one{
  @at-root .class {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Css:

```
.class {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Хм, получается, что просто через запятую @at-root вместе с детьми перечислить нельзя. То есть для моего вопроса первые 2 ответа не применимы, тк не дают нужного результата. А №3 все равно не избавляет от лишней записи каскада, разве что они будут находится рядом.

Comment: и `&` рядом с ним не работает

Comment: @kizoso верно, не самое гибкое решение, но иногда лучше чем ничего

Comment: Пожалуй)) в моем случае не сильно красиво, но все же помогло)

Comment: @kizoso, _Хм, получается, что просто через запятую `@at-root` вместе с детьми перечислить нельзя._ - почему нельзя? вроде ж работает

Comment: @Grundy вместе с `@at-root` знак `&` игнорируется, и дети которые должны быть из под родителя, тоже вылетают наверх.

Comment: @kizoso, у меня что-то не вылетают, можешь пример показать как пробуешь какой результат получается и какой должен был быть?

Comment: @Grundy https://codepen.io/kizoso/pen/WyggzP

Comment: @kizoso, ага, понял в чем проблема, забавно, но решается простым переносом `@at-root` в начало списка и добавления `'& '` перед дочерним селектором: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXqPKy

Comment: @Grundy правда, забавно) спасибо